# CentOS, ZPanel and Cloudflare DNS error

Tags: domain-name-system, a-record

I am stuck in a problem. I have a VPS which gave me a dedicated IPv6 address and a shared IPv4 address. I have tunneled it and installed ZPanel on my centOS server. Now I can access ZPanel from 31.220.48.155:22277 and I have also added a new domain in zpanel. I am adding 31.220.48.155:22277 in Cloudflare A record but it wont allow saying "You entered '31.220.48.155:22277' which is not a valid IP address." I am stuck. Please Help...

Comment: Have you tried putting in just the IP address without the port number into the "IP Address" field?

Comment: You bill your self as `the world's leading Information Technology company providing quality solutions` and you don't know that you can't have a port in an A record? I think you need to make some changes on your website...

Comment: Stop bragging poeple. I am here to learn something. To find a solution. It is not that I haven't tried, but can't figure it out as I am new to VPS. BTW thanks for the comment.

Comment: Joker:- Do you know how I got this scars..?
@Jacob:- Do YOU know how I got this points..?
Joker:- No
Jacob:- I Brag People

Comment: @VRTechnologies We're not bragging here. A simple read of the definition of an A record will give you the answer that you look for. As far as the second comment I *really* have no idea what you're trying to tell me.

Answer (score 5):

You can't put the port number in there. The IP address is 31.220.48.155.

Comment: I know that i can't put in the port number in there. It is a shared ipv4 address for which my port 80 is forwarded to port 22277.